# How can I achieve a Jquery toggle function with my current code?

Tags: html, jquery

This is what my code looks like:

```js
$("#1").click(function() {
  $("#active1").toggle();
});

$("#2").click(function() {
  $("#active2").toggle();
});
```

```html
<div class="carouselTypo">
  <p class="carouselTypo__p" id="1">A</p>
  <p class="carouselTypo__p" id="2">B</p>
  <p class="carouselTypo__p" id="3">C</p>
  <p class="carouselTypo__p" id="4">D</p>
  <p class="carouselTypo__p" id="5">E</p>
</div>
<hr>

<div id="active1" class="activeingreds" style="display: none;">
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor officia quae, quisquam minus beatae a error corrupti officiis velit? Sit.</p>
</div>
<div id="active2" class="activeingreds" style="display: none;">
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus, illo.</p>
</div>
<div id="active3" class="activeingreds" style="display: none;">
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo reprehenderit accusantium saepe voluptate deleniti excepturi delectus aut, libero accusamus magnam nam architecto vero dolorum illo culpa vitae. Necessitatibus nam saepe mollitia eveniet.</p>
</div>
<div id="active4" class="activeingreds" style="display: none;">
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem, ipsum.</p>
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem, ipsum.</p>
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem, ipsum.</p>
</div>
<div id="active5" class="activeingreds" style="display: none;">
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, porro ipsa neque quas exercitationem debitis?</p>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to show a certain div when clicking on a certain P class (with the ID).
I tried using the toggle function in Jquery, which works but it always just adds another div to be visible.

Comment: Please add your current JS code to the question so that we can help you debug it

Comment: Apologies, I added it.

Comment: I dont see an active1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's isn't an `#active1` or `#active2` element in the HTML, but there does appear to be `#active3` and higher, so I assume this is just a typo.

With regard to the question, to DRY up the logic you can use a `data` attribute on the `p` elements which are clicked to target the `.activeingreds` element to be displayed, whilst hiding the others. Try this:

```js
let $activeingreds = $('.activeingreds');

$('.carouselTypo__p').on('click', e => {
  $activeingreds.hide().filter(e.target.dataset.target).show();
});
```

```css
.activeingreds { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carouselTypo">
  <p class="carouselTypo__p" data-target="#active1">A</p>
  <p class="carouselTypo__p" data-target="#active2">B</p>
  <p class="carouselTypo__p" data-target="#active3">C</p>
  <p class="carouselTypo__p" data-target="#active4">D</p>
  <p class="carouselTypo__p" data-target="#active5">E</p>
</div>
<hr>

<div id="active1" class="activeingreds">
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor officia quae, quisquam minus beatae a error corrupti officiis velit? Sit.</p>
</div>
<div id="active2" class="activeingreds">
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus, illo.</p>
</div>
<div id="active3" class="activeingreds">
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo reprehenderit accusantium saepe voluptate deleniti excepturi delectus aut, libero accusamus magnam nam architecto vero dolorum illo culpa vitae. Necessitatibus nam saepe mollitia eveniet.</p>
</div>
<div id="active4" class="activeingreds">
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem, ipsum.</p>
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem, ipsum.</p>
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem, ipsum.</p>
</div>
<div id="active5" class="activeingreds">
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, porro ipsa neque quas exercitationem debitis?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually answers my question. It works perfect. Thank you! Learned something new today :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$(".carouselTypo__p").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr("id")
  $("#active" + id).toggle();
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$(".carouselTypo__p").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr("id")
  $("#active" + id).toggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carouselTypo">
  <p class="carouselTypo__p" id="1">A</p>
  <p class="carouselTypo__p" id="2">B</p>
  <p class="carouselTypo__p" id="3">C</p>
  <p class="carouselTypo__p" id="4">D</p>
  <p class="carouselTypo__p" id="5">E</p>
</div>
<hr>

<div id="active1" class="activeingreds" style="display: none;">
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor officia quae, quisquam minus beatae a error corrupti officiis velit? Sit.</p>
</div>
<div id="active2" class="activeingreds" style="display: none;">
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus, illo.</p>
</div>
<div id="active3" class="activeingreds" style="display: none;">
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo reprehenderit accusantium saepe voluptate deleniti excepturi delectus aut, libero accusamus magnam nam architecto vero dolorum illo culpa vitae. Necessitatibus nam saepe mollitia eveniet.</p>
</div>
<div id="active4" class="activeingreds" style="display: none;">
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem, ipsum.</p>
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem, ipsum.</p>
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem, ipsum.</p>
</div>
<div id="active5" class="activeingreds" style="display: none;">
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, porro ipsa neque quas exercitationem debitis?</p>
</div>
```

While the above solution works its not the best so I suggest this.

**Demo 2**

```js
$(".carouselTypo__p").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("data-id")
  $(".activeingreds").hide();
  $("#" + id).toggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carouselTypo">
  <p class="carouselTypo__p" data-id="active1">A</p>
  <p class="carouselTypo__p" data-id="active2">B</p>
  <p class="carouselTypo__p" data-id="active3">C</p>
  <p class="carouselTypo__p" data-id="active4">D</p>
  <p class="carouselTypo__p" data-id="active5">E</p>
</div>
<hr>

<div id="active1" class="activeingreds" style="display: none;">
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor officia quae, quisquam minus beatae a error corrupti officiis velit? Sit.</p>
</div>
<div id="active2" class="activeingreds" style="display: none;">
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus, illo.</p>
</div>
<div id="active3" class="activeingreds" style="display: none;">
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo reprehenderit accusantium saepe voluptate deleniti excepturi delectus aut, libero accusamus magnam nam architecto vero dolorum illo culpa vitae. Necessitatibus nam saepe mollitia eveniet.</p>
</div>
<div id="active4" class="activeingreds" style="display: none;">
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem, ipsum.</p>
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem, ipsum.</p>
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem, ipsum.</p>
</div>
<div id="active5" class="activeingreds" style="display: none;">
  <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, porro ipsa neque quas exercitationem debitis?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to think about making a reference to the associated element into the link to prevent repetiting your code like

```
<div class="carouselTypo">
            <p class="carouselTypo__p" id="1" data-target="active1">A</p>
            <p class="carouselTypo__p" id="2" data-target="active2">B</p>
            <p class="carouselTypo__p" id="3" data-target="active3">C</p>
            <p class="carouselTypo__p" id="4" data-target="active4">D</p>
            <p class="carouselTypo__p" id="5" data-target="active5">E</p>
        </div>
        <hr>

        <div id="active1" class="activeingreds" style="display: none;">
            <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor officia quae, quisquam minus beatae a error corrupti officiis velit? Sit.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="active2" class="activeingreds" style="display: none;">
            <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus, illo.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="active3" class="activeingreds" style="display: none;">
            <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo reprehenderit accusantium saepe voluptate deleniti excepturi delectus aut, libero accusamus magnam nam architecto vero dolorum illo culpa vitae. Necessitatibus nam saepe mollitia eveniet.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="active4" class="activeingreds" style="display: none;">
            <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem, ipsum.</p>
            <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem, ipsum.</p>
            <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem, ipsum.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="active5" class="activeingreds" style="display: none;">
            <p class="activeingreds__p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, porro ipsa neque quas exercitationem debitis?</p>
        </div>
```

and do a think like

```
$('.carouselTypo__p').click(function(e) {
    $('#'+$(e.target).data('target')).toggle();
})
```

The id of the element to be toggled is stored in the data-target attribute. You just have to select the element using this attribute.